# Unity + Android SurfaceTexture Update Error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm trying to create a Unity-based VR app that uses the Android ExoPlayer for video playback. Unity assets like "EasyMovieTexture" work great for the MediaPlayer, but I need to use the ExoPlayer. I basically have the following:

Java (Android Library):

```
public void setSurfaceFromTexture(int textureHandle) {
    this.surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textureHandle);
    this.surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
} 
public void updateSurfaceImage() {
    this.surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
}
```

C# (Unity):

```
mediaPlayer.Call("setSurfaceFromTexture", texture.GetNativeTexturePtr().ToInt32());
```

However, I keep getting the following error when I call `updateSurfaceImage` each frame:

> ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to update texture contents (see logcat for details)

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Note: I've used the Oculus MoviePlayerSample and got it to work with ExoPlayer. But the Oculus libraries don't work outside the GearVR.

Answer (score 3):

I did not get this working and have decided to go with a different approach. However, what I learnt from someone who actually does have this system working is that you can't use Unity Textures - you need to use `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` with `SurfaceTexture`.

You first have to do the following:

```
glGenTextures(1, &uiTextureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, uiTextureID);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then using the FBO, copy the SurfaceTexture over to the Unity texture. Each frame. An example of doing this in C++ is provided with the [Oculus Mobile SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/) (in the MediaSurface.cpp file)

Answer (score 1):

[SurfaceTexture in Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) say that

> updateTexImage() may only be called on the thread with the OpenGL ES context that contains the texture object

Also, I think you have to set `setOnFrameAvailableListener` on that thread as well to let `updateTexImage()` work, not sure though.